# Spring AOP - How can I design an advice which when applied to an API, applies the aspect to all methods in the File everytime an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-aop

Spring AOP - How can I design an advice which when applied to an API, applies the aspect to all methods in the File everytime an exception is thrown? For ex - it is analogous to applying advice at every catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)?

Define a pointcut:

> the execution of any method defined by the AccountService interface:
>
> ```
> execution(* com.xyz.service.AccountService.*(..))
> ```

Use an `@Around` advice

> ```
> import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
> import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
> import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
>
> @Aspect
> public class AroundExample {
>
>     @Around("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.businessService()")
>     public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
>         // start stopwatch
>         Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
>         // stop stopwatch
>         return retVal;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

use a `try { return pjp.proceed();} catch (Exception e) {...}` to catch all exceptions and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below can be used to trace all the exceptions in all the files in any package

> 1. Add a central controller for processing all the requests for method execution.
> 2. Configure the aspect to trace all the requests for method execution.

**1.Sample Interceptor:**

```
    package spring;

    import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
    import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

    public class CustomMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation method) throws Throwable {
            Object returnValue = null;
            try {
                returnValue = method.proceed();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //handle in some generic way
                throw e;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

**2.AOP configuration**

```
    <aop:config>        
            <aop:pointcut id="interceptorPointCut" expression="execution(* com.custom.package..service.*.*(..))"/>
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="interceptingAdvice" pointcut-ref="interceptorPointCut"/>   
    </aop:config>       

    <bean id = "interceptingAdvice" class="spring.CustomMethodInterceptor">         
    </bean>
```

The aspect has to be written in such a way that it can trace all requests to spring-managed beans.